# Find $g(y-1)$ given $g(y)=y^2+2y+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $g(y)=y^2+2y+1$, then $g(y-1)= \dots$

$g(y-1)=(y-1)^2+2(y-1)+1$.

This is where I get stuck.

Comment: At that point, you're done.

Comment: The book brought it down to y^2

Answer (score 2):

Life is better with $(a-b)^{2} = a^{2} - 2ab + b^{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Starting from where you're at:
\begin{align}
g(y-1)&=(y-1)^2+2(y-1)+1 \\
&= \underbrace{\left(y^2 - 2y +  1\right)}_{(y-1)^2} + \underbrace{2y -2}_{2(y-1)} + 1\\
&= y^2  -2y +2y +1 +1 -2\\
&= y^2
\end{align}

EDIT:  Whenever we write $a^2$, that means $a\cdot a$.  So, in this particular instance, we can think of $y-1$ as our "$a$."

\begin{align}
(y-1)^2 &= (y-1)(y-1) \\
&= y(y-1) -1(y-1) \quad \text{(distribute first factor)}\\
&= (y\cdot y - y\cdot 1) + (-y+1) \quad \text{(distribute again)}\\
&= y^2 -y-y + 1\\
&= y^2 -2y + 1
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I understand all of this but one part where does the "-2y+1" come from?

Comment: @James Does that help?

Comment: Yes thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two options:

Either you could expand things out after your first step...

```
 g(y-1) = (y-1)^2 + 2(y-1) + 1
        = (y^2 - 2y + 1) + (2y - 2) + 1
        = y^2 -2y + 2y +1 -2 +1
        = y^2
```

Alternately you could note that g(y) can be factorised...

```
 g(y) = y^2 + 2y + 1
      = (y+1)(y+1)
```

so

```
 g(y-1) = ((y-1) + 1)((y-1) + 1)
        = (y)(y) = y^2
```